# download server generated file (.vcf)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file, dialog, download

i have an interactive aspx dialog with some address data (like name, email, address,...). Now i want the user to be able by clicking a button to download the address data as vcf file.
Now, generating the vcf compatible string isn't the problem. But saving it to the client is.

While it returns the vcf string just fine, it does not open a "Save AS"-dialog. Below i attached my logic for the file download. 
What am i doing wrong?

(Maybe it's worth mentioning that the code-behind function calls come from java script,...)

Thanks for any helpfull answers in advance.

```
Public Sub SaveText(ByVal Text As String)

        Dim FileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName()

        Using sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter(Server.MapPath(FileName + ".txt"))
            sw.WriteLine(Text)
            sw.Close()
        End Using

        Dim fs As System.IO.FileStream = Nothing


        fs = System.IO.File.Open(Server.MapPath(FileName + ".txt"), System.IO.FileMode.Open)
        Dim btFile(fs.Length) As Byte
        fs.Read(btFile, 0, fs.Length)
        fs.Close()

        With HttpContext.Current.Response
            .Clear()
            .Buffer = True
            .Expires = 0
            .AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName)
            .AddHeader("Content-Length", btFile.Length.ToString)
            .ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
            .BinaryWrite(btFile)
            '.OutputStream.Write(btFile, 0, btFile.Length())
            .Flush()
            .End()
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: do you change file extension while sending vcf file?

Comment: @hkutluay No, not at this point. For now i would be happy if i just got a save-as dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was not the above mentioned logic itself. The way i handeled the response on the client side was just wrong. The calling java script function expected something else.
I would elaborate in more detail, but this stuff here is so home grown and proprietary, it wouldn't make any sense. 
Cheers.